# How can I get list of instances along with attached volumes and their respective type and size?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am working on the AWS CLI for the first time and need help.

I want the query to get list of ec2 instances along with attached volumes and their respective type and size using AWS CLI.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

You would use [describe-instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html) to obtain a list of all Amazon EC2 instances in your account in a particular Region.

You can use [describe-volumes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-volumes.html) to obtain a list of Amazon EBS Volumes. There is an `Attachments` field that lists which EC2 instances are connected to each volume, and also fields for `Size` and `VolumeType`.

Given that you would need to join the Instance and Volume information together, it might be easier to do this from a programming language like Python rather than using the AWS CLI.